# How can I make multiple if statement in the same line? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

In the following **DataFrame** of pandas there is a column called "grupo_edad", the values of the column are:

```
De 0 a 4 años, De 5 a 9 años, De 10 a 14 años, De 15 a 19 años, De 20 a 24 años,...,De 85 a 89 años, 90 y más años.
```

I want to **create a new column with a condition**, where the two values: "De 0 a 4 años" and "De 5 a 9 años" take the same value, for example: 0-9. Analogously for the rest.

The problems come when trying to make the **if statement in the same code line**. I have done this:

```
df['nueva_columna']=df['grupo_edad'].apply(lambda x: 
                                 "0-9" if (x=="De 0 a 4 años" or x=="De 5 a 9 años") else 
                                 "10-19" if (x=="De 10 a 14 años" or x=="De 15 a 19 años") else
                                 "20-29" if (x=="De 20 a 24 años" or x=="De 25 a 29 años") else
                                 "30-39" if (x=="De 30 a 34 años" or x=="De 35 a 39 años") else                              
                                 "40-49" if (x=="De 40 a 44 años" or x=="De 45 a 49 años") else                              
                                 "50-59" if (x=="De 50 a 54 años" or x=="De 55 a 59 años") else
                                 "60-69" if (x=="De 60 a 64 años" or x=="De 65 a 69 años") else
                                 "70-79" if (x=="De 70 a 74 años" or x=="De 75 a 79 años") else "80+")
```

But it is not working properly ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A30vk.png)), all of them are working but there are problems with: "10-19", "70-79" and "80+". So... how am I understanding wrongly the if statement ? Is weird there are some that work perfectly

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: it could be space prblm for exmple "De 20 a 24 años" is different from " De 20 a 24 años " so it get throwing into the else condition

Comment: Your could write this more clearly if you used a `def` statement instead of a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for leading/trailing spaces. One easy way to fix your code is `str.strip()`:

```
df['nueva_columna']=df['grupo_edad'].str.strip().apply(lambda x: 
                                 "0-9" if (x=="De 0 a 4 años" or x=="De 5 a 9 años") else 
                                 "10-19" if (x=="De 10 a 14 años" or x=="De 15 a 19 años") else
                                 "20-29" if (x=="De 20 a 24 años" or x=="De 25 a 29 años") else
                                 "30-39" if (x=="De 30 a 34 años" or x=="De 35 a 39 años") else                              
                                 "40-49" if (x=="De 40 a 44 años" or x=="De 45 a 49 años") else                              
                                 "50-59" if (x=="De 50 a 54 años" or x=="De 55 a 59 años") else
                                 "60-69" if (x=="De 60 a 64 años" or x=="De 65 a 69 años") else
                                 "70-79" if (x=="De 70 a 74 años" or x=="De 75 a 79 años") else "80+")
```

However, you can make your code a bit easier to read with `pd.cut`:

```
start_age = df['grupo_edad'].str.extract('De (\d+)', expand=0).astype(int)
df['nueva_columna'] = pd.cut(start_age, bins=range(0,80,10), 
                             right=False,
                             labels=["0-9","10-19","20-29","30-39",
                                     "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79"]
                            ).fillna('80+')
```

Comment: I think e.g., `numpy.select` is the real answer here

Comment: @PaulH sure, I was just editing a similar approach.